# Error in PHP with bool arithmetic in loops

Tags: php, loops, boolean

It looks there is an error in PHP with boolean arithmetic in loops.

In this particular example I test if all important form fields (represented by objects) were set. The `var_dump` is for debuging purposes.

```
$allset = true;
foreach ($forms as $one):
    $allset = $one->wasSet() and $allset;
endforeach;
var_dump($allset);
foreach ($more as $one):
    $allset = $one->wasSet() and $allset;
endforeach;
var_dump($allset);
$allset = $iwasthere->wasSet() and $allset;
var_dump($allset);
```

This code may fail. It is possible the first dump returns false and the second returns true.

**My question.**

How can I avoid this error and have short and clean code?

---

*P.S.*

I use `if` blocks for now.

Comment: I'm still surprised when I find someone's using the `foreach(): ... endforeach;` syntax :-)

Comment: I dont see any error :? Also I cant imagine, what `$forms` or `$more` should contain. @Alvaro: I use this syntax, if I mix PHP/HTML. There its harder to find out to which statement a `}` belongs. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that the `=` operator has a [higher precedence](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) than `and` operator. So the assignment expression is just part of a logical expression and the whole expression is equivalent to this:

```
($allset = $one->wasSet()) and $allset;
```

Either put the logical expression in parentheses or use `&&` instead of `and`:

```
$allset = ($one->wasSet() and $allset);
$allset = $one->wasSet() && $allset;
```

Comment: This is the best approach you should follow when using the boolean experssions

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't there be a

```
$allset = true;
```

before the second foreach loop?

Comment: No. I want to test content of two arrays and one "scalar" as a whole. The var_dump is for debuging purposes.

Comment: So, you mean that the dumps should never return (false, true) but the other 3 combinations shoulb be possible. OK, I misunderstood how you were using $allset in the 2 loop.

Comment: I have few objects in two arrays ($forms and $more) and one under name $iwasthere. Objects have the method wasSet() returning bool. I want test if all objects return true.

Answer (score 0):

(code below is compatible with php 5 only)

Your code has another mistake:

```
$allset = $iwasthere->wasSet(); // this overwrites all previous checks
```

Should be

```
$allset = $iwasthere->wasSet() && $allset;
```

Also it would be better if you have a class for form instead array of fields

class Form{
  protected $fields = array();
  function addField($field){
    $this->fields = $field;
    return $field;
  }
  function allSet(){
    $allSet = true;
    foreach($this->fields as $field){
      $allSet = $allSet && $field->wasSet();
    }
    return $allSet;
  }
}

to add fields you can (option one) extend the class:

```
RegisterForm extends Form{
  function __construct(){
    $name = $this->addField(new FormField('name'));
    $action = $this->addField(new FormField('action'));
    $action->hidden = true;
  }
}
```

then you use it like this:

```
$form = new RegisterForm();
```

Or (option two) you can add fields after you create the form

```
$form = new Form();
$name = $form->addField(new FormField('name'));
```

....

and then usage is pretty simplified:

....

```
if(!$form->allSet()){ // that looks like clean code
  ...error...
}
```

if you have 2 forms:

```
$allSet = $form1->allSet() && $form2->allSet();
if( !$allSet ){
  ...error...
}
```

if you need to make the same loop twice your code is already diry

Comment: This is very small project. It is less code not to write a class.

Comment: Well, you asked for a clean code. If it's a small project, then why form fields are objects? I'll write the class for you: class FormField{protected $fields; function addField($field){$fields[] = $field;} function allSet(){/* put your loop here - you'll have to write it anyway*/}}. Didn't took more than a minute. How is it compared to the whole time of the project (even if the project has to be made for one hour).

Comment: I use classes for form fields mainly to generate html tags. In my definition of clean code creating a whole class for one method isn't clean.

Comment: of course you will have other methods - they will come with the need to do other code you need to write. What I meant that overhead of writing it in a class is not big because you write the code anyway, the only difference is that in class it'll be packed and grouped by functionality. I bet you have a lot of code in the middle of nowhere that gets the form post data and creates object for each field. you can put this code into the Form class. You don't need to always use object oriented programming in the whole meaning - you can use classes to group functions and data. it's more clean.